# Custom JSON serializable for different types of response

Tags: android, json-deserialization

The server responses of all my APIs are in the following format :

```
{
"code":200,
"status":"success",
"response": {/*different type of responses in all APIs*/}
}

{
"code":200,
"status":"success",
"response": [/*different type of responses in all APIs*/]
}
```

I have created a class for the response :

```
public class Response {
    @SerializedName("code")
    int code;
    @SerializedName("status")
    String status;
    @SerializedName("response")
    String response;
}
```

How can I get different kind of responses in the response variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use generic for your response message:

```
public class Response<T> {
    @SerializedName("code")
    int code;
    @SerializedName("status")
    String status;
    @SerializedName("response")
    T response;
}
```

Your response with corresponding data model like this:

```
Response<List<DataModel>>, Response<DataModel>, etc...
```

Convert with Gson:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Response<T>>(){}.getType();
Response<T> response = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: but how to use Gson with it?